# CocoaPods. podspec. How to generate Swift file in script_phases and then append it to source_files?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, podspec

I have my own framework. There is a phase with `:execution_position => :before_compile` in `script_phases` that generates `.swift` file.
I've added the filepath of future generated file to `source_files`.

File was generated while compiling, but not added to compile sources, so it won't be compiled.

How should I fix this?

The similar question, but adding filepath to Output files didn't give the desired effect.
[Xcode 10, sourcery & swiftlint build phases order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407545/xcode-10-sourcery-swiftlint-build-phases-order)